# Bigquery temporary tables location EU instead US

Tags: google-bigquery

we are using Bigquery and want to use the beta feature of temporary tables
(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#temporary_tables). Now we have discovered that all of this temp tables are located in the US.
Is there somehow a possibility to "locate" this in the EU? All our data needs to be located in the EU and not outside.

Thanks in advance for your answers.
regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create the dataset, the location cannot be changed.

You need to create new temp tables and select EU location. When you query data using the Cloud Console, click `More -> Query settings`.
For `Processing Location`, click `Auto-select` and choose your data's location, in your case: `European Union (EU)`.

You can test it with example query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TempTable
(x INT64, y STRING);

INSERT INTO TempTable
VALUES (1, 'Big');

INSERT INTO TempTable
VALUES (2, 'Query');

SELECT * FROM TempTable;
```

After that, when you go to `Job Information -> Destination Table` (Click on Table name), you will get details about TempTable in `Table info -> Data location`, which is `EU`.